# Firebase v9 onAuthStateChanged only fires on initialization

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, react-hooks

I am in the process of migrating my React app to firebase v9. Currently I am working on the auth context. 
The problem is that the `onAuthStateChanged()` callback only fires once during initialization, but not on `signInWithEmailAndPassword()` or `signOut()`. Refreshing the page shows that the auth state has indeed changed, only the listener won't fire.
Have there been any changes in v9 that might be causing this or am I missing something?

Context
*AuthContext.jsx*

```
export const AuthContext = createContext(undefined);

export const AuthWrapper = ({ children }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(undefined);

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (currentUser) => {
      setUser(currentUser);
    });
    return unsubscribe();
  }, []);

  return <AuthContext.Provider value={user}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>;
};
```

Usage
*index.jsx*

```
import { AuthWrapper } from "./context/AuthContext";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <AuthWrapper>
      <App />
    </AuthWrapper>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
```

*App.jsx*

```
import { useContext } from "react";
import { AuthContext } from "./context/AuthContext";

function App() {
  const user = useContext(AuthContext);

  return <>{user ? <Dashboard /> : <Landing />}</>
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your clean up effect setup is wrong.

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (currentUser) => {
      setUser(currentUser);
    });
    // to fix:
    return () => { unsubscribe() }
    // equivalent to:
    return unsubscribe
    // but not:
    return unsubscribe(); // it cleans up immediately after the first call
  }, []);
```